# Unity вложенные префабы (Nested prefabs)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть у меня префаб - блок. Из этих блоков построены разные здания - так же префабы. Как сделать так, что при добавлении/изменении свойства компонента в блоке, все дочернии элементы здания (блоки) так же меняли свои свойства в соответствии к префабу своему изначальному.

Comment: Приведите пример, не совсем понятно, что вы имеете в виду под "компонент в блоке" и "дочерние здания (блоки)".

Comment: Есть у меня Префаб `Block`. Добавляю пустой элемент и заполняю его префабами (дочерними их делаю), и получается префаб `Tower`. И теперь я хочу, чтобы когда я изменяю что - то в экземляре префаба `Block` (например добовляю звук), и нажимаю кнопку `Apply`, то менялись свойства не только префаба-базового, но и всех экземплярова прифабов на моей сцене.

Comment: То, что вы хотите сделать, простыми словами называется "nested prefabs".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ на 10 октября 2018 года**

---

Данная "конструкция" из добавления префабов в качестве детей другого префаба называется в англоязычных терминах "Nested prefabs". **Unity не поддерживает nested prefabs**.

[Данная "фича" довольно старая - разработчики ее выпрашивают вот уже 9 долгих лет](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/editor-nested-prefabs):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[И разработчики ее наконец дождались, точнее дождутся в Unity 2018.3.0:](https://unity3d.com/ru/unity/roadmap)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

На момент публикации этого ответа (смотри шапку) **последний релизный билд** - **Unity 2018.2.11f1**.

Но по ссылку выше уже можно опробовать бета версию 2018.3.0. Стоит ли переносить весь свой проект на бета-билд ради не прямо уж необходимого функционала вложенных префабов? Вряд ли. Но на всякий случай оставлю ссылку на FAQ по новой системе префабов:
[Introducing new Prefab workflows](https://blogs.unity3d.com/ru/2018/06/20/introducing-new-prefab-workflows/)

Comment: Спасибище большое:)